# Par4all installation

Tags: installation, dependencies

[PictureHere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppzYy.png)First of all i would like to thank everyone on stackoverflow for helping to people from beginners -like me- to advanced users.

I am trying to install Par4All automated parallelization tool. It has many dependencies to install. And older version of ubuntu to work with gcc 4.5.5. Ubuntu 12 works with it. The repository is not an easy usual one. It does not have a configure file and so make command does not work. In src folder simple_tools folder i found p4a_setup.py. I installed program after installing dependencies but in terminal p4a command does not work. Installer gave me an ending message to source the /usr/local/par4all/...sh file for bash but i could not figure out what to do.

Repository: https://github.com/Par4All/
Dependencies: autoconf, libtool, flex, bison, cproto, libreadline-dev, ncurses-dev, swig, ipython, python-dev, libgmp3-dev, libmpfr-dev, subversion

I would really appreciate any help here.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by source /usr/local/par4all/etc/par4all-rc.sh then using p4a command.I bumped into cannot create workspace error but that is it for tonight. One problem at a time.